# Get the selected value in a choice list using symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony2 version 2.6
I want to know how to get the value of the selected value in a choice list. this my action :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // On récupère l'EntityManager
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // Pour récupérer une annonce unique : on utilise find()
     $rep= $em->getRepository('PFEUserBundle:Employee');
     $employees  = $rep->findAll();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($employees)
        ->add('employees', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'PFEUserBundle:Employee',
            'property'=>'matricule',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        ))
        ->add('voir','submit')
        ->getForm();

    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $mat=$request->request->get('employees');
        $employee=$rep->findByMatricule($mat);
        //=====> get the employee
        $session = $request->getSession();
        // stocke un attribut pour une réutilisation lors d'une future requête utilisateur
        $session->set('emp', $employee);


        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pfe_employees_employee_view', array('id' => $employee->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('PFEEmployeesBundle:Employee:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

the problem is here :

```
$mat=$request->request->get('employees');
$employee=$rep->findByMatricule($mat);
```

after selecting a choice and submiting it gives me this error :

```
Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$request->get("employees")` contains the ID and the findByMatricule method only accepts objects. So you should either change it to:

```
$mat = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("PFEUserBundle:Employee")->find($request->get("employees"));
```

Or change the findByMatricule method so it works with id's, but then it would be better to add a method called findByMatriculeId

Answer (score 0):

What you get in the request is an id of an object, it's the form object that transforms that it into and object(shortly speaking) from the database(if the field in the form is of type entity or its a collection of entities) so

```
$request->request->get('employees')
```

returns an id, lets say 1 while

```
$form->get('employees')->getData()
```

will return an object of class PFEUserBundle:Employee